# Java EE EJB keeps trying to add new entry to database from one request

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I am still rather inexperienced with JavaEE. I'm attempting to create a prototype and have learnt as much as I can in a week however now I am truly stuck.

I send a json object over POST from an android application then add the contents to a database. The request comes in through my servlet which extracts the data then creates a new Entity and populates it with the data. I then send the entity to a message-driven bean which calls a save function:
    public void save(Object object) {
            em.persist(object);
            em.flush();
    }
The servlet sends the entity via jms/Queue queue.

The problem: After deploying and sending a request from the application, it tries to insert the information into my database (which it does) but then it appears to keep trying to do this, filling my console with the following:

```
WARNING: Local Exception Stack
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461):    org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2012/03/14-AAAA' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
```

My thoughts are that it the message might not be being removed from the Queue properly or perhaps somewhere it has decided to keep sending the message. I don't think that is the case however I'm not entirely sure how the EntityManager works. I'm really not sure what code to include apart from all of it.

Any help would be great, I'm really in a pinch!

Thanks,
Dan

Edit: Using MySQL database and Glassfish server.

Comment: Can you add how are you creating entity, is it in some transactional method in EJB bean.